# BitmapImage spark in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5, bitmapimage

i want to migrate my application from **Flex 3.6** to **Flex 4.5**.

Let say i have this code in **Flex 3.6** :

```
<mx:Image id="lImage"
          source="@Embed(source='assets/loading.swf')"
/>
```

Further, this `<mx:Image/>` becomes `<s:BitmapIamge/>` in **flex 4.5**. So we have the following code :

```
<s:BitmapImage  id="lImage"
        source="@Embed(source='assets/loading.swf')"
/>
```

but i have an error about the transcoding of *loading.swf*. Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved it's about the generation path of a **SWC** file